# Query With Both Join and Derived Table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to add row counts to an existing query but am getting an error

***unknown column 'pl.GroupNumber' in 'on clause'***

I'm apparently going to answer this too in case it helps someone else as, after writing all this here, it occurred to me to reverse the FROM to:

***FROM (SELECT @row_number:=0) AS t, parts_listing pl ***

which seemed to do the trick! Don't quite understand why it worked but it did.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    (@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS RowNum,
    pl.ID,
    pn.ID AS SubID,
    IF(ListType,(SELECT MAX(ID) FROM parts_notes
    WHERE PageNo=429
        AND ListType IS NOT NULL AND SubPage IS NULL AND
        (BasePart IS NOT NULL AND Models IS NOT NULL
        AND (BasePart=pl.PartNo
        AND pl.Models LIKE CONCAT('%', Models ,'%')))
        OR  (BasePart IS NOT NULL AND Models IS NULL
        AND BasePart=pl.PartNo) ),NULL) AS SubMax,
    ListType,
    IndentText,
    BaseGroup,
    BaseName,
    GroupName,
    Title,
    `Name`,
    pl.Models,
    pl.PartNo,
    pn.PartNo AS SubPartNo,
    pl.Quantity,
    pn.Quantity AS SubQuantity,
    pn.Description AS SubDescription,
    ListType,
    Column_1,
    Column_2,
    Column_3,
    Column_4,
    Column_5,
    Column_6,
    Column_7,
    Column_8,
    COALESCE(pl.GroupNumber, pn.GroupNo) AS GroupNo,
    COALESCE(pl.Description, pn.Description) AS Description,
    COALESCE(pl.PageNo, pn.PageNo) AS PageNo,
    COALESCE(pl.SubPage, pn.SubPage) AS SubPage,
    COALESCE(pl.RevDate, pn.RevDate) AS RevDate,
    COALESCE(pl.Edition, pn.Edition) AS Edition
    FROM parts_listing pl, (SELECT @row_number:=0) AS t 
    LEFT JOIN parts_notes pn ON pl.GroupNumber=pn.GroupNo
    AND ((ListType < 5 AND (pl.PartNo=BasePart AND BasePart IS NOT NULL) OR BasePart IS NULL)
    OR ((ListType > 4) AND (pl.GroupNumber=pn.GroupNo OR pl.PartNo=BasePart)))
WHERE BaseGroup=30 AND pl.PageNo=429 AND (pl.SubPage IS NULL
    AND pn.SubPage IS NULL)
    AND (pl.PageNo = pn.PageNo OR pn.PageNo IS NULL)
    AND (pl.SubPage = pn.SubPage OR pn.SubPage IS NULL) 
ORDER BY pl.ID, pn.ID 
LIMIT 150;
```

Comment: Please add aliases to all columns. We can't guess where each column is coming from, and that's critical to help you in this case.

Comment: Does the table `parts_listing` have a column named `GroupNumber`?

Comment: Also avoid merging old school JOINs syntax (`,`) with modern one (`LEFT JOIN`). It just adds to the mess.

Comment: Thank you. Parts_listing has GroupNumber; parts_notes has GroupNo and I believe that all the others without aliases are parts_listing. Getting ready to catch a plane so can't check now but will once I get settled back in. However, the main question here was in getting a value for RowNum and fixing the error on FROM parts_listing pl, (SELECT \@row_number:=0) AS t and that is working with it reversed to FROM (SELECT \@row_number:=0) AS t, parts_listing pl. Not sure how I could have done it without ( , ) since it's not an actual join as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use commas in the `FROM` clause, even when you intend `CROSS JOIN`.  The scoping rules are not what you expect, which is why you get an unknown column.

I put parameter conditions on the end, so I would write this as:

```
FROM parts_listing pl LEFT JOIN 
     parts_notes pn 
     ON pl.GroupNumber = pn.GroupNo AND
        ((ListType < 5 AND
         (pl.PartNo = BasePart AND BasePart IS NOT NULL
         ) OR BasePart IS NULL
        ) OR
        ((ListType > 4) AND
         (pl.GroupNumber = pn.GroupNo OR pl.PartNo = BasePart)
         )
        ) CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT @row_number := 0) params
```